# OnCompletion(message) of javax.jms.CompletionListener is not getting executed after message sent Successfully

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis for a simple chat application. The message sending is working fine, and the consumer is consuming the message by executing `onMessage()`. But neither the `onCompletion()` nor the `onException()` methods of `javax.jms.CompletionListener` are not getting executed.

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://TJ12AA041-PC:61616");
Connection con = factory.createConnection();
con.start();

Session session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Topic topic = session.createTopic("examp2");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(null);        
TextMessage txt = session.createTextMessage();
txt.setText("Hello Hello");
producer.send(topic, txt, new CompletionListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onException(Message msg, Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to send Messaeg : "+ex.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(Message msg) {     
        System.out.println("Message sent SuccessFully");
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: apache-artemis-2.10.1

Comment: I just tested this code on ActiveMQ Artemis [2.11.0](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=activemq/activemq-artemis/2.11.0/apache-artemis-2.11.0-bin.zip&action=download) (which was *just* released) and it worked fine. The `onCompletion` method was invoked when the message was sent successfully.